# How to make container height match the child listView item size

Tags: flutter, dart

I build my app homeScreen that contains multiple part of widget and most of the is basically a listView with different size, and I put them all inside column widget.

the problem is this listView is actualy come from streamBuilder so the content inside the list is dynamic (come from firebase) so there is gonna be a time it will contain 5 items for example or 0 items.

And as far as I know when I use streambuilder or listview in general I need to warp this widget in something like container with predefined height and if the listview items only 1 and I predefined the height to be for 5 items then it will show a big white space of nothing (since the container is for 5 items but to that user, he/she only have 1 items)

```
Container(
  height: screenHeight * 0.4,
  child: StreamBuilder<List<Place>>(
    stream: database.placesStream(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return ListItemsBuilderNoScroll<Place>(
        snapshot: snapshot,
        itemBuilder: (context, place) => _buildPlaceList(screenWidth, screenHeight, place),
      );
    },
  ),
),
```

So how to fix this issue or am I using the wrong widget for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a legit problem, but more of a logic problem than design. Instead of directly building the listview by default, you may check of data being available on the stream you are listening to.  Set a flag or something on the basis of which you decide whether to build the listview to display or not.

Additionally, once the get the list you need to display on the list view, you may also change the size of the container by the checking the list length.

Anyway, this is a seven-month-old question, hopefully, you have found the solution to your problem.

Happy Coding!
GS